# Getting error when using object[] in constructor when using reflections in java

Tags: java, class, reflection

So, the title sais everything. When i try to pass arguments in an Object array using .newInstance i get an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at me.voxed.textrpg.RoomCreator.setNorth(RoomCreator.java:44)
>       at me.voxed.textrpg.Game.(Game.java:89)
>       at me.voxed.textrpg.Program.main(Program.java:6)

This is the function im using:

```
    public void setNorth(String block, String... args){
    try {
        Object[] argsObj = args;
        Class<? extends Block> clazz = (Class<? extends Block>) (GameRegistry.getBlock(block));
        _north = clazz.asSubclass(Block.class).getConstructor(Object[].class).newInstance(argsObj);
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException
            | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And clazz is this class:

```
public class BlockNPCSpawnBars extends BlockNPC {

public BlockNPCSpawnBars(Object[] args) {
    super(args);
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760569/problem-with-constructing-class-using-reflection-and-array-arguments

Comment: Darn! I should have searched more :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-) takes variable arguments. When you pass it an array, it translates to a varargs call, as if each element in that array were a separate argument to the constructor.

This is generally solved like the following:

```
...newInstance((Object) argsObj);
```

That will ensure the array is passed as the singular argument, like your actual constructor is expecting.

Comment: That was fast! Thanks for an informative and quick solution. :)

Comment: No problem. If you think the issue's adequately solved, you can consider accepting my answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244864 Also, note that the explicit `(Object)` cast is basically just a shorthand for the code shown in the link from @luanjot. (Varargs sees the `Object` and creates an array around it with 1 element.)

Comment: I was going to, i dont think i can accept an answer until 10 minutes have passed. Thanks again :)