# How do I call a constructor in java via reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I am dumping CSV via jackson. I have a couple of mapping classes and want to pass the mapping class to the CSV export method.

I have an abstract class, extended it to each of the csv column formats. I pass the name of the class to the export function then want to map the data via the constructor for the class and dump it as CSV.

All fine until I get to creating the class that does the mapping and is to be exported.

Invocation exception/Invalid number of parameters exception.

```
protected String mapTransactionsToCSV(List<Object[]> results, String rowClassName) 
  Class rowClass  = Class.forName(rowClassName);
  for (Object[] component : results)
    VehicleAbstract vehicle  = (VehicleAbstract) rowClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Object[].class).newInstance(component);
    csv.append(mapper.writer(schema).writeValueAsString(vehicle));
  }
}
```

My specific class (and abstract class, which I just copied to try). has 2 constructors

```
public Bus() {} 
public Bus(Object[] component) {}
```

Comment: Good question - thanks for formatting it nicely, and giving a nice, neat example. Always helps =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Problem with constructing class using reflection and array arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760569/problem-with-constructing-class-using-reflection-and-array-arguments)

The problem is that `newInstance` already takes an array of objects. You need to wrap your object array in *another* array. Something like this:

```
component = {component}; // Wrap in a new object array
VehicleAbstract vehicle  = (VehicleAbstract) rowClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Object[].class).newInstance(component);
```

This is the reason that you're getting an invalid number of parameters - you're passing each item in that object array as a separate parameter, instead of one parameter (the array of objects).

Comment: If you think it's a duplicate, please just flag to close as such. Eventually, [when you have 3k reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), you'll also be able to vote.

Comment: I'll do that in the future, @SotiriosDelimanolis. I didn't want to go flag-happy now that I've just earned the privilege to. Besides, I'd gone to the trouble of answering it before I even found the SO solution (after a second search).